# Compare two javascript arrays and remove duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare two different arrays together, One previous and one current. The previous set of data contains:

```
[
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"}
]
```

The new set contains:

```
[
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Shield"}
]
```

So as you can see here Test1 has obtained a new item. I've tried to compare these two arrays together a few ways but with no avail.

**The methods I've tried:**

This one just returns the entire array. Not individual items.

```
Items_Curr.filter(function(item) { return !Items_Prev.includes(item); });
```

This method just returns 3 Undefined's.

```
Items_Curr.map(e => { e.member_name });
```

I've been looking through trying to find a way of doing this but other posts just explain methods to determine change in simpler arrays.

**E.G** `[a,b] - [a, b, c]`

Update:

The end goal is I'd like to create a new array 'NewItems' which would contain an array of all the newly added names and items. So if there is change, I would like that to be broadcasted, if there is no change, then ignore until the function has been ran again.

Comment: You need to write your own compare method.

Comment: I think your question is lacking some information. What is the desired output? What do you want it to look like. Like, do you want to know what's new or remove duplicates?

Comment: Like @Shubham said, you're going to need to compare each key value pair in each item, then push the items that are unique to a new array

Comment: I've updated the post @Sinaesthetic also fair enough, How would i compare each key value, Would that be through a for loop for each item? My main array has 270 items in it. So would that means it needs to scan all 230 items for 231 times if there is a new item? That seems very load intensive.

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON array. JSON is _always_ a string. You have an array of objects.

Comment: Also, what is "unique" ? Technically, all 3 objects in both arrays are unique combination.

Comment: Removed `json` tag. JavaScript Object Notation is a string representation of JavaScript objects. JavaScript objects are JavaScript objects, not JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realistically you want to do something like:

```
[a, b, c] - [a, b]
```

Which would give you `c`. You can achieve this using `.some`, which allows you to "customize" the includes functionality.

See example below:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"}
];

const arr2 = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Shield"}
];

const res = arr2.filter(({member_name:a, item:x}) => !arr1.some(({member_name:b, item:y}) => a === b && x === y));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This also works like a charm, I wasn't aware you could add {} elements into a filter or some line.

Comment: @T3rr11 no worries, this is known as [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 2):

If you know your properties will *always be in the same order* you can use `JSON.stringify` to serialize the objects and compare the results:

```js
const Items_Prev = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"}
]

const Items_Curr = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Shield"}
]

const serialized_Items_Prev = Items_Prev.map(i => JSON.stringify(i));
const NewItems = Items_Curr.filter(i => !serialized_Items_Prev.includes(JSON.stringify(i)));
console.log(NewItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this you need to do if keys of objects are not changing and new items are only added at last.

```js
const array1 = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"}
];

const array2 = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Shield"}
];

const compare = (array1, array2) => {
 if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
   return false;
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i += 1) {
    if (array1[i].member_name !== array2[i].member_name) {
     return false;
    }
    
    if (array1[i].item !== array2[i].item) {
     return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
};

console.log(compare(array1, array2));
```

If order of objects are changing, then you need to write sorting algo for array and then compare.

Comment: what is array items are not in Order?

Comment: I feel like this is a great answer but for larger arrays it would create quite a big load, would it not?

Comment: I also do like your compare lengths of arrays, That does help with the performance impact!

Comment: @T3rr11 it will. But first answer is only comparing strings. If the orders are changing then it will cause issues.

Comment: @T3rr11 basically filter and some are also using loops inside it. So my answer is only using single loop and loop is also breaking as soon as it is getting the diff. this function looks big but I think it is more efficient.

Comment: Ahh fair enough, yeah i had a feeling some and filter do the same, But it's just alot cleaner to use those. Nothing wrong with your answer it should work the exact same by the looks of things :D

Answer (score 0):

You can acheieve it using array methods filter() and findIndex()

Filter current array with  out put of findIndex() function on previous array

```js
var prevItems = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"}
]

var currItems = [
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Sword"},
  {"member_name":"Test1","item":"Shield"},
  {"member_name":"Test2","item":"Shield"}
]

var newItems = currItems.filter(function(currItem ){
  return  prevItems.findIndex(function(prevItem){
     return prevItem.member_name ==  currItem.member_name &&
            prevItem.item == currItem.item
  }) == -1
})


console.log(newItems)
```